# Wordpress Archive Header not display correct fata

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to set a custom post number per page for archive using a wp query. Below my code for my archive.php file.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$postpage = intval($met_data['met_archive_post_page']);

$archive_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => $postpage,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($archive_args); 

?>

<div class="post-archive-box">

    <?php
        if ( is_day() ) :
            echo _e( '<span>Daily Archives</span>', 'met' );
            printf( __( '<h1>%s</h1>', 'met' ), get_the_date() );

        elseif ( is_month() ) :
            echo _e( '<span>Monthly Archives</span>', 'met' );
            printf( __( '<h1>%s</h1>', 'met' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'met' ) ) );

        elseif ( is_year() ) :
            echo _e( '<span>Yearly Archives</span>', 'met' );
            printf( __( '<h1>%s</h1>', 'met' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'met' ) ) );

        else :
            _e( '<h1>Archives</h1>', 'met' );

        endif;
    ?>

</div>

<div class="ec-container">

    <div id="ec-content">

        <div id="ec-main" <?php if($met_data['met_archive_post_sidebar'] == 0) : ?>class="fullwidth"<?php endif; ?>>

            <?php if($met_data['met_archive_layout'] == 'grid' || $met_data['met_archive_layout'] == 'full_grid') : ?><ul class="ec-grid"><?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php if($met_data['met_archive_layout'] == 'grid') : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part('met-content', 'grid'); ?>

                <?php elseif($met_data['met_archive_layout'] == 'list') : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part('met-content', 'list'); ?>

                <?php elseif($met_data['met_archive_layout'] == 'full_list') : ?>

                    <?php if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) : ?>

                        <?php get_template_part('met-content'); ?>

                    <?php else : ?>

                        <?php get_template_part('met-content', 'list'); ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php elseif($met_data['met_archive_layout'] == 'full_grid') : ?>

                    <?php if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) : ?>

                        <?php get_template_part('met-content'); ?>

                    <?php else : ?>

                        <?php get_template_part('met-content', 'grid'); ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part('met-content'); ?>

                <?php endif; ?> 

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php if($met_data['met_archive_layout'] == 'grid' || $met_data['met_archive_layout'] == 'full_grid') : ?></ul><?php endif; ?>

                <?php met_pagination(); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

        <?php if($met_data['met_archive_post_sidebar'] == 0) : else : ?>

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It works fine because it get from database the correct value for number of posts per page, but is not displayed the archive header with the correct data (monthly archive). It get the word "Archives" only. Seems that the code below not work properly. What's wrong?

```
<?php
            if ( is_day() ) :
                echo _e( '<span>Daily Archives</span>', 'met' );
                printf( __( '<h1>%s</h1>', 'met' ), get_the_date() );

            elseif ( is_month() ) :
                echo _e( '<span>Monthly Archives</span>', 'met' );
                printf( __( '<h1>%s</h1>', 'met' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'met' ) ) );

            elseif ( is_year() ) :
                echo _e( '<span>Yearly Archives</span>', 'met' );
                printf( __( '<h1>%s</h1>', 'met' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'met' ) ) );

            else :
                _e( '<h1>Archives</h1>', 'met' );

            endif;
        ?>
```

Thnaks in adv.

Comment: What do the is_day(), is_month() and is_year() functions do? Did you check their output?

Comment: Check if archive is monthly daily or yearly archive and print on screen eg. MARCH 2016 if list of posts is for march 2016. But seems that the problem is the wp_query on top of file. If I remove it all works fine. Probably I missed something, but I need that query because I need to set a custom number of post per page. Thanks